# Any video player library in android which can play both youtube videos and normal videos other than YoutubePlayer API?

Tags: android-videoview, android-video-player, youtubeplayer

I am using two players and two different views to play youtube and normal videos. when one player is playing and visible other is hidden.. but i m having conflict in views. is there any video player library in android that can play both type videos in single player. ?

Comment: Asking for a specific library usually leads to opinion based answers, so probably this question will be flagged as offtopic. I would suggest doing some research, trying to implement whatever component you will find, and coming back with a coding problem if you get into trouble.